# Return mutiple value for on column in sql select

Tags: mysql, sql, database, group-concat

For Example This is my table(copied).

```
id  customer        product 
1   Tizag           Pen 
4   Gerald Garner   19" LCD Screen  
5   Tizag           19" LCD Screen  
6   Gerald Garner   clock
```

I want to select the whole table. And the result has to be like this:

```
customer        product 
Tizag           Pen,19" LCD Screen
Gerald Garner   19" LCD Screen,clock
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Select customer ,
Group_Concat(product SEPARATOR ',') as Product
from TableName group by customer
```

[**SQL Fiddle Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/82294/1)

Answer (score 1):

No need to use "," as seperator , it comes by default

```
 select customer, group_concat(product) as product
 from tableName
 group by customer
```